# Scrapy: Unable to understand a log about robots.txt

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

My question is that if this log means the website cannot be scraped? I changed my user agent to look like a browser but it didn't help. Also, I omitted the "s" inside the "start_requests" but it wasn't helpful either. Even I changes "ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False" in seetings.py but wasn't helpful.

Here is the log I got:

```
2020-11-17 18:06:41 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2020-11-17 18:06:41 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2020-11-17 18:06:42 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://podcasts.apple.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2020-11-17 18:06:42 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://podcasts.apple.com/us/genre/podcasts-arts/id1301> (referer: None)
2020-11-17 18:06:43 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://podcasts.apple.com/us/genre/podcasts-arts/id1301> (referer: https://podcasts.apple.com/us/genre/podcasts-arts/id1301)
2020-11-17 18:06:43 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://podcasts.apple.com/us/genre/podcasts-arts-books/id1482> (referer: https://podcasts.apple.com/us/genre/podcasts-arts/id1301)
2020-11-18 17:29:49 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2020-11-18 17:29:49 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 1342,
 'downloader/request_count': 4,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 4,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 67297,
 'downloader/response_count': 4,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 4,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 18, 13, 59, 49, 133234),
 'httpcache/hit': 4,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 5,
 'log_count/INFO': 9,
 'request_depth_max': 2,
 'response_received_count': 4,
 'robotstxt/request_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 3,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 3,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 3,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 3,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 18, 13, 59, 48, 758371)}
2020-11-18 17:29:49 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Here is a part of my spider:

```
import scrapy


class ApplePodcastSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'apple_podcast'
    allowed_domains = ['podcasts.apple.com']

    def start_requests(self):
            yield scrapy.Request(url='https://podcasts.apple.com/us/genre/podcasts-arts/id1301',
                callback= self.parse_categories, dont_filter=True)


    def parse_categories(self, response):
            categories=response.xpath("//ul[@class='list column first']")
            for category in categories:
                category_name=category.xpath(".//li/a/text()").get()
                category_link=category.xpath(".//li/a/@href").get()
                yield response.follow(url=category_link, callback=self.parse_sub_categories, meta={'category_name': category_name}, dont_filter=True)

    def parse_sub_categories(self, response):
            category_name=response.request.meta['category_name']
            sub_categories=response.xpath("//ul[@class='list column first']/li")
            for sub_category in sub_categories:
                sub_category_name=sub_category.xpath(".//ul[@class='list top-level-subgenres']/li/a/text()").get()
                sub_category_link=sub_category.xpath(".//ul[@class='list top-level-subgenres']/li/a/@href").get()
                if sub_category_link is None:
                    pass
                else:
                    yield response.follow(url=sub_category_link, callback=self.parse_alphabet, meta={'category_name': category_name,'sub_category_name': sub_category_name}, dont_filter=True)
                

    def parse_alphabet(self,response):
            category_name=response.request.meta['category_name']
            sub_category_name=response.request.meta['sub_category_name']
            alphabets=response.xpath("//div[@class='content']/div[@class='padder']/div[@class='selectedgenre']")
            for alphabet in alphabets:
                alphabet_link=alphabet.xpath(".//ul[@class='list alpha']/li/a[@class='selected']/@href").get()
                yield response.follow(url=alphabet_link, callback=self.parse_podcasts_link, meta={'category_name': category_name, 'sub_category_name': sub_category_name}, dont_filter=True)
     

    def parse_podcasts_link(self, response):
            category_name=response.request.meta['category_name']
            sub_category_name=response.request.meta['sub_category_name']
            podcasts=response.xpath("//div[@class='grid3-column']")
            for podcast in podcasts:
                podcast_name=podcast.xpath(".//div[@class='column first']/ul/li/a/text()").get()
                podcast_link=podcast.xpath(".//div[@class='column first']/ul/li/a/@href").get()
            
            for podcast in podcasts:
                podcast_name=podcast.xpath(".//div[@class='column']/ul/li/a/text()").get()
                podcast_link=podcast.xpath(".//div[@class='column']/ul/li/a/@href").get()
            
            for podcast in podcasts:
                podcast_name=podcast.xpath(".//div[@class='column last']/ul/li/a/text()").get()
                podcast_link=podcast.xpath(".//div[@class='column last']/ul/li/a/@href").get()
                yield response.follow(url=podcast_link, callback=self.parse_podcasts, meta={'category_name':category_name,'sub_category_name':sub_category_name,'podcast_name':podcast_name}, dont_filter=True)    


    def parse_podcasts(self, response):
            category_name = response.request.meta['category_name']
            sub_category_name = response.request.meta['sub_category_name']
            podcast_name = response.request.meta['podcast_name']
            podcasts = response.xpath("//div[@class='ember-view l-content-width section section--hero product-hero']/section[@class='ember-view']/div[@class='l-row']")
            for podcast in podcasts:
                rate = podcast.xpath(".//div[@class='l-column small-12 medium-7 large-8 small-valign-top']/div[@class='l-row']/div[@class='l-column small-7 medium-12 small-valign-top']/header[@class='product-header product-header--padded-start podcast-header']/ul[@class='product-header__list podcast-header__list']/li[2]//ul[@class='inline-list inline-list--mobile-compact']/li[@class='inline-list__item']/figure/figcaption/text()[1]").get()
                rating_number = podcast.xpath(".//div[@class='l-column small-12 medium-7 large-8 small-valign-top']/div[@class='l-row']/div[@class='l-column small-7 medium-12 small-valign-top']/header[@class='product-header product-header--padded-start podcast-header']/ul[@class='product-header__list podcast-header__list']/li[2]//ul[@class='inline-list inline-list--mobile-compact']/li[@class='inline-list__item']/figure/figcaption/text()[3]").get()
               

                yield{
                    'category_name':category_name,
                    'sub_category_name':sub_category_name,
                    'podcast_name':podcast_name,
                    'rate':rate,
                    'rating_number':rating_number
                }
            next_page=response.xpath("//div[@class='content']/div[@class='padder']/div[@class='selectedgenre']/ul[@class='list paginate']/li/a[@class='selected']/@href").get()
            if next_page:
                yield scrapy.Request(url=next_page, callback=self.parse_podcasts, dont_filter=True)
```

Can anybody help me understand what the problem is and how I can solve it?

Thank you!!!

---EDIT1---

The log I got after changing the "allowed_domains" part:

```
2020-11-18 13:49:18 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2020-11-18 13:49:18 [scrapy.extensions.httpcache] DEBUG: Using filesystem cache storage in C:\Users\shima\projects\apple_podcasts\.scrapy\httpcache
2020-11-18 13:49:18 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2020-11-18 13:49:18 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://podcasts.apple.com/robots.txt> (referer: None) ['cached']
2020-11-18 13:49:18 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://podcasts.apple.com/us/genre/podcasts-arts/id1301> (referer: None) ['cached']
2020-11-18 13:49:18 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://podcasts.apple.com/us/genre/podcasts-arts/id1301> (referer: https://podcasts.apple.com/us/genre/podcasts-arts/id1301) ['cached']
2020-11-18 13:49:18 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://podcasts.apple.com/us/genre/podcasts-arts-books/id1482> (referer: https://podcasts.apple.com/us/genre/podcasts-arts/id1301) ['cached']
```

---EDIT2---

The log I got after removing the "try and except" statement:

```
2020-11-18 13:53:07 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2020-11-18 13:53:07 [scrapy.extensions.httpcache] DEBUG: Using filesystem cache storage in C:\Users\shima\projects\apple_podcasts\.scrapy\httpcache
2020-11-18 13:53:07 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2020-11-18 13:53:07 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://podcasts.apple.com/robots.txt> (referer: None) ['cached']
2020-11-18 13:53:07 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://podcasts.apple.com/us/genre/podcasts-arts/id1301> (referer: None) ['cached']
2020-11-18 13:53:07 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://podcasts.apple.com/us/genre/podcasts-arts/id1301> (referer: https://podcasts.apple.com/us/genre/podcasts-arts/id1301) ['cached']
2020-11-18 13:53:07 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://podcasts.apple.com/us/genre/podcasts-arts-books/id1482> (referer: https://podcasts.apple.com/us/genre/podcasts-arts/id1301) ['cached']
```

Comment: You don't have to add `www` in `allowed_domains` value. Try by  replacing `www.podcasts.apple.com` to `podcasts.apple.com` in `allowed_domains` variable. refer: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.allowed_domains

Comment: I'd guess that the problem is that you wrapped all your class methods in try except blocks which will prevent the spider from executing properly. You should remove that and fix the indentation.

Comment: Thank you, @ShubhamKadam. I did what you said and edited the post to see the log I got (EDIT1).

Comment: Thanks, @Patrick Klein, I removed "try and except" and edited the post in EDIT2 to see the log I got

Comment: Does it mean that I am banned or something?

Comment: Can you please reduce your code down to the essential parts i.e. remove all the wikipedia stuff at the top?

Comment: @tomjin, I reduced the part you said.

Comment: @shimamasaeli I think you need to reduce more to try and make a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), e.g. in your `parse_poscasts` method two out of your three `for` loops are pointless

Comment: On that page, there are three columns of podcast names and links, each column has a different class attribute. So, I wrote a "For" loop for each column. @tomjn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**There is nothing wrong in your execution log.**

```
2020-11-17 18:06:42 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://podcasts.apple.com/us/genre/podcasts-arts/id1301> (referer: None)
```

Those are debug messages, it's telling you that your spider crawled the mentioned URL. If you don't want to see it you can your `LOG_LEVEL='INFO'` in your `settings.py`.

Also, you didn't defined any items to be scraped, just defined the pages to be crawled, so the spider will go through the pages and eventually close.

#### Edit:

I haven't checked your whole code, but I did executed once and noticed a few issues.

This selector will return empty:

```
 alphabets=response.xpath("//div[@class='content']/div[@class='padder']/div[@class='selectedgenre']")
```

You used `@class` instead of `@id` for both `'content'` and `'selectedgenre'`. The XPath should be:

```
//div[@id='content']/div[@class='padder']/div[@id='selectedgenre']
```

Notice that this will return only **ONE** selector, so you shouldn't be iterating over it. You probably want to iterate over the links.

**This will also return empty:**

```
alphabet_link=alphabet.xpath(".//ul[@class='list alpha']/li/a[@class='selected']/@href").get()
```

As there is no `a` element with the class `'selected'` (by default) in the XPath you are using.

I imagine there will be more broken XPaths, so you should go over the selectors to make sure your XPaths are correct and that **they are returning what you expect**. No issues related to `robots.txt` btw.

Comment: Thank you, @renatodvc. I edited the post and put all the spider's code there. I guessed it may not be necessary so I just put a part of my spider's code. Actually, I have asked it to scrape so many elements. and you can now see all of it above.

Comment: The problem is the output .xml file gets created. But when I try to open it, I get "XML parse error". And based on the log, no item gets scraped.